# Difficulty understanding the number of bits stored in memory for each variable

Tags: python-3.x, memory, bit

[image: bit manipulation]

I know a data type float can store 32 bits(speed) but what i dont understand is how can a transformation x*4 reduce the data size from 32 to just 10 bits (Speed). can anyone help me understand this concept?

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers for data size?  They have nothing to do with how many bits Python uses to store a variable.

Comment: You might want to checkout this article [Understand How Much Memory Your Python Objects Use](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understand-how-much-memory-your-python-objects-use--cms-25609)  for more information on how python stores data.

Comment: @itprorh66 you mean if i divide the speed from 0-250 by 4 will it not decrease the number of bits stored in memory?. i have tried to use sys.getsizeof but i think this function tells us about the actual memory consumed that python interpreter uses. I want to know about the memory size consumed by the reference

Comment: my professor said that a float number takes 32 bits of memory but for speed if we transform it by dividing the numbers 0-255 by 4 we get the memory size to 10 i dont understand the concept behind this.

Comment: First of all let's differentiate between the amount of memory used by python to store a variable and the minimum number of bits required to store a floating point number of a certain size.  In the case of python, it will utilize the same number of bits if you keep the number or divide it by 4.  Python pretty much allocates memory for variables based solely on type.  Now in the case of minimum number of bits required to represent a number, if the max size of the number is 1/4 of the max size of another number, you can represent the smaller number with fewer bits.  .